# How to clone div and insert button together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, clone

I just want to clone and insert button in right handed-side of this cloned one.

my javascript looks like this:

```
 $('.frame .portlet').click(function (e) {


        if ($(e.target).is(".portlet-content") || $(e.target).is(".portlet-header")) {
            cancel: 'ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick';
            var $this = $(this), $error;

            // for duplicate
            if ($this.hasClass('added') && !$this.hasClass('newPortlet')) {
                $error = $this.next('.clone-error');
                if (!$error.length) {
                    $error = $('<span />', {
                        'class': 'clone-error',
                        html: '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" style="width: 300px"> This question is already added!</div>'
                    }).insertAfter(this);
                }
                $error.stop().show().delay(800).hide(1);
            } else if (!$this.hasClass('newPortlet')) {
                $this.addClass('added').clone(document.getElementById(this.id)).addClass('newPortlet').("<button>hi</button>").appendTo('#creation .newFrame');

                $msg = $('<span />', { html: '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="width: 300px"> This question is added to Add List!</div>' }).insertAfter(this);
                $msg.stop().show().delay(800).hide(1);
                count++;
                add.html("<span id='newExam' class='badge' style='background-color: lightgreen; border-color: green'>" + count + "</span>");
            }

        }
    });
```

I want it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: Please do provide us a little more Code (HTML) or even a jsfiddle link so we can help you better ;)

Comment: I think you can do this very simple, and I recommended you, don't mix `pure js` and `jQuery`. jsfiddle link will be useful

Comment: `clone(document.getElementById(this.id) === clone(this)`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ppositive/du5eu1t9/

Comment: I just posted jsfiddle link, please check and help me @highqweb

Comment: see above @MehdiDehghani

Comment: see above @charlietfl

Comment: not really clear what demo should do, or what isn't working as expected

Comment: when it cloned to second div, I want it's coming with button like the pic above. I'm sorry for confusing T^T @charlietfl

Comment: Change line 20 to this: `$this.addClass('added').clone(document.getElementById(this.id)).addClass('newPortlet').appendTo('#creation .newFrame').append('<span class="edit">Eidt</span><span class="delete">Delete</span>');`
You can also store the append element to a variable.

Comment: @PloyyPpositive did you mean, when I clicked on each block, one copy of the block appears after dotted line, with 2 buttons, edit & remove? if so, please explain what is the job of this 2 buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a reference to the cloned object....then manipulate that object by appending to it.

Change:

```
$this.addClass('added').clone(document.getElementById(this.id))
      .addClass('newPortlet').appendTo('#creation .newFrame');
```

To:

```
  // create clone object
  var $clone = $this.addClass('added').clone(this);
  // now can append to clone
  $clone.append('<button>TEST</button>');
  // then insert clone to dom          
  $clone.addClass('newPortlet').appendTo('#creation .newFrame');
```

By creating the object as variable it makes it much easier to read and see various steps. I think your main issue was just having to many steps in a chain to make logic easy to follow

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/du5eu1t9/1/)**</kbd>